# htaccess dynamic url redirect to static url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have searched for my specific htaccess redirect from dynamic url to static url but can't found proper one. So here is the question.

**I want to redirect** 
www.example.com/directory/?year=2014&month=September
www.example.com/directory/?year=2014&month=October
www.example.com/directory/?year=2015&month=December
and so on

**To**
www.example.com/directory/2014/September
www.example.com/directory/2014/October
www.example.com/directory/2015/December
and so on

Hope you will definitely help with step by step process and how it work. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in the `/directory/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/(\w+)/?$ ?year=$1&month=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Can you plz explain step by step flow. Like what ^, (\d+) will do?

Comment: You can see explanation for this regexp here: http://regex101.com/r/eZ2eC0/2 on the right